# Is the error rate always the Bayesian one?

Tags: bayesian, python, measurement-error

I know [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_error_rate) that the Bayes error rate is: $${\displaystyle p=1-\textstyle \sum _{C_{i}\neq C_{\text{max,x}}}\int \limits _{x\in H_{i}}P(C_{i}|x)p(x)\,dx}$$
where $x$ is an instance, $C_i$ is a class into which an instance is classified, $H_i$ is the area/region that a classifier function $h$ classifies as $C_i$.

For instance for a multiclass classifier results `predicted["pred_idx_euc"]` and the actual labels `predicted["target"]` I did the following error rate measure :

```
>>>def accuracy(target, predicted):
       acc = (target==predicted).sum()/len(target)
       return acc
>>>error_rate = 1 - accuracy(predicted["target"], predicted["pred_idx_euc"])
```

It doesn't look exactly the same way ...

Comment: Maybe it is standard notation but I do not know it, hence, this question is hard to read: I suspect that you want to do multiclass classification and you have classes $C_1, ..., C_k$. I suspect further that $i$ runs through the index set $\{1,...,k\}$. What is $C_{\text{max},x}$? What is $H_i$? From the term I also suspect that you use a naive Bayes classificator, is that correct? So you want to know: When using a naive Bayes classifier, is the empirical accuracy equal to this integral (?)?

Comment: @FabianWerner Thanks for your comment, I tried to update in order to clarify. Actually my classifier are an euclidean distance and a cosine one from their results it gives a predicted class in `predicted` which might or might not be the same of `target`. I think it is a naive Bayes classifier.

Comment: The bayes error is the lowest possible 'true' error a model can ever attain, i.e. it is the error of the 'best possible model' you could ever come up with. We can almost never compute this error (nor the model that is connected to it) because we do not have the (common) probability distribution $P_{X,Y}$ of the data variable $X$ and the answer variable $Y$. If for any reason you can conclude that your model attains this error then congrats: you have found the best model ever possible. Still, it is unclear to me what you are asking: Do you have a concrete model and ask whether its...

Comment: empirical error is equal to the bayes error? Due to the fact that you present some python code I assume that you have a concrete problem and you have a concrete model and you computed the empirical accuracy (resp. 1-acc). And now you ask whether this is equal to the Bayes error, is that correct?

Comment: @FabianWerner Yes, exactly. I'm going to add a bit more of it which you can [found here](https://github.com/antoinecomp/qasolver/blob/master/unsupervised.ipynb) meanwhile.

Comment: Well, if you ask whether or not two numbers are the same then maybe you should compute both numbers and see for yourself... so, you can easily compute the empirical accuracy but can you compute the bayes error?

Comment: @FabianWerner Yes, the problem is that if I know how to compute the  empirical error I don't know how to compute the Bayesian error from [the model](https://github.com/antoinecomp/qasolver/blob/master/unsupervised.ipynb). I didn't knew the one I was computing was only the empirical, I thought it was the Bayesian as well.

Comment: You *can not* do that unless you *know* the *true* distribution. So the short answer is: you cannot tell. So my question to you is: what is the greater goal of doing so? What do you want to achieve by comparing these numbers?

Comment: @FabianWerner The reason is an idea of user20160 in [this previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362824/how-to-create-a-binary-threshold-from-cosine-distance-between-1-d-arrays). It would potentially help me to create a binary threshold from Cosine distance between 1-D arrays whose arguments of the maxima gives me `predicted["pred_idx_euc"]` for instance.

Comment: What he meant was more like: "try to add more features and fit more complicated models". The histograms that you have produced tell you that this feature 'distance to the closest sentence' (however that was precisly defined) does not help you very much in predicting whether or not the sentence has an answer but this is actually stuff that belongs to the other question.